# AutoGenerateBindingRedirects property in csproj does not generate all redirects

Tags: .net, csproj

I'm setting the `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` and `GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType` properties to `true` in a .NET Framework class library .csproj file. However, whereas the generated .dll.config file includes redirects for a bunch of system assemblies, there are none generated for any of the NuGet package references.

Here is a snippet of my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>MyLibrary</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>MyLibrary</RootNamespace>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>key.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <Version>6.5.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects" Version="161.46437.65" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" Version="14.0.1016.290" />
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" Version="21.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The generated .dll.config file includes redirects for Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Newtonsoft.Json, System.Memory, etc., but none for any of the packages above. I need it to include a redirect for `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` specifically.